# Where's the verb in 'Enterprise has one DW and data marts source their information...'?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, sentence-meaning

I have this sentence from a slide in my class:

> Enterprise has one DW and data marts source their information from it

Where *DW* is a shortcut for [data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).

I couldn't find the verb in that sentence. Is it *source*? If yes, what does the sentence mean? Does it mean that the [data marts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart) extract their data from the DW?

Comment: What does "enterprise" mean or refer to in this sentence? I'm interested because of a [previous question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40393/access-applications-are-widespread-in-the-enterprise-what-is-meant-by-enterp) that used the word.

Comment: @δοῦλος, this is a different use of "Enterprise", I believe: here, it's the name of a computer program (or possibly, the name of a *version* of a computer program, in the sense of *Windows 7 Home* vs. *Windows 7 Professional*, where you could use "Professional" as a shorthand to refer to the latter).

Comment: In the parlance of software development, it refers to a business enterprise in its entirety, usually meaning its entire technical infrastructure.

Comment: Companies sometimes call a software edition "Enterprise" when they want to imply that that edition is the one [business enterprises](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40393/#40425) should purchase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two verbs in this sentence:

> Enterprise **has** one DW and data marts **source** their information from it.

Yes, data marts extract their information from the DW. They use the DW as their information source.

Comment: I got the idea, but data marts extract `information`, not `data` if you would like to correct. many thanks

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - I guess there's no big difference between "information" and "data".

Comment: Don't get me started please. I spent three years in bachelor degree studying how to extract information from data. There is 100000000 differences between them

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - for the technical and specialized purposes, yes. For the purpose of explaining what word in a sentence is a verb and for pointing out what word functions as the verb's complement or "semantic object", I guess not.

Comment: in the context of finding the verb in an English sentence, you can ignore them, that is why i accepted your answer thought your description is not correct from informatics point of view.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - I see: *data* is raw ore, information is refined ore, and the DW is the mine-cum-refining factory. If you feel awkward, I'll edit the answer (0: Voila!

Comment: It may be true that *data* and *information* have different definitions when used to refer to their *technical* meanings in certain fields. Nevertheless, as used in everyday English in many contexts, they are at least partially interchangeable. That is the way people use these words, and trying to straight jacket people into using the terms in a way that reflects technical usage is misguided.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **source** is a verb in that sentence. This sentence might illustrate what's going on:

> Data marts source their information from the enterprise's one data warehouse.

In this context, **source** means "get". More specifically, it means that the data marts use the data warehouse as the source of their information. The author chooses to write "source" rather than "get" in order to convey all the usual connotations of the noun "source" (which is certainly more familiar than the verb "source"). Those connotations include suggesting that the data marts rely exclusively on the data warehouse and that the information from the data warehouse is authoritative.